# I uploaded a laravel 8 on my subdomain and i received error

Tags: laravel

i uploaded my laravel 8 project to my subdomain and i received this error

file_put_contents(E:\Projects\API\api-worforce\storage\framework/sessions/UkfntojT5Qzf99w9TR6Jvxs6iOBKlJ3TvLB6clTF): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

its still using local directory

Comment: make sure you have write permission to `storage` folder

Comment: yes i have the write permission for the folder and all inside it

Comment: It could be a caching issue you should run `php artisan optimize` on your remote server after ssh into it.

Comment: okay i will try it

Comment: HI @Coola thankyou its working now

Answer (score 0):

Some of Laravel files are so-called cached. Therefore, the cache must be removed to fix this error as well.

How to fix the problem(two methods):

- Method 1: Just go to the following path of your project in Laravel host and rename the config.php file to config_old.php or delete this file completely:

```
bootstrap / cache
```

- Method 2: If the first method is not effective in solving the problem, run the following command this time:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan congif:cache
```